# How to use tooltip with translate tag ? AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, internationalization, translate

I have a button and button script code :

```
<a ng-hide="custom" href="#" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="Zoom in" onclick="ga('send','event','Navigation Tool','Navigation Tool','Zoom in')" class="onezoomin" ng-click="navSelected('onezoomin');">
    <img src="assets/images/1428276334_expand.png" class="navImageStyle">
</a>
```

and I want to translate tag for this code.  How can I do ?

for example :

```
<a ng-hide="custom" href="#" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="translate='navMenu.hide.zoomin'" onclick="ga('send','event','Navigation Tool','Navigation Tool','Zoom in')" class="onezoomin" ng-click="navSelected('onezoomin');">
    <img src="assets/images/1428276334_expand.png" class="navImageStyle">
</a>
```

but Didnt work.

navMenu is json file.

so navMenu.json code :

```
    {
         "navMenu":{
         "hide": "Hide",
         "hide": {
             "zoomin": "Zoom In"
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `translate` directive from angular-translate?

Comment: yes I want to languages support @MichaelP.Bazos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `translate` ***filter*** for that, not the directive:

```
tooltip="{{'navMenu.hide.zoomin' | translate}}"
```

And if your version of angular is above 1.3, you can use the following syntax for performance matter:

```
tooltip="{{::'navMenu.hide.zoomin' | translate}}"
```

The syntax above will prevent keeping watchers in memory.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. Did i must change this ??  :  `onclick="ga('send','event','Navigation Tool','Navigation Tool','Zoom in')` @MichaelP.Bazos

Comment: When we arrived on the button  write this : "navMenu.hide.zoomin" @MichaelP.Bazos

Comment: The `onclick` is not related to that. The fact that you don't get the translation is probably a problem with your angular-translate configuration. What does `{{'navMenu.hide.zoomin' | translate}}` outside tooltip, for example in a div block, display?

Comment: Seems you should write `'hide.zoomin' | translate` considering the json you posted.

Comment: yes in a div block . this is code : `<div id="top_menu" ng-switch="isAuthenticated()" ng-controller="NavbarController">
    <div id="navMenuDiv"  ng-controller="navController">` and after  `<a ng-hide="custom" href="#" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{::'navMenu.hide.zoomin'|translate}}" onclick="ga('send','event','Navigation Tool','Navigation Tool','Zoom in')" class="onezoomin"
               ng-click="navSelected('onezoomin');">
                <img src="assets/images/1428276334_expand.png" class="navImageStyle">
            </a>`   Where do you think the problem ? @MichaelP.Bazos

Comment: As I told, it seems your key is `hide.zoomin` instead of `navMenu.hide.zoomin`. If you still don't see the translated label, I can't tell further than that as I don't know your configuration.

Comment: by the way hide is a button and zoomin is a button. Does it matter ?? @MichaelP.Bazos